# xquery newbie-how to add support for the custom Xquery functions at xqueryfunctions.com, to my java app

Tags: java, xquery, saxon

Excuse me if my question sounds silly-- I am new to XQuery as well as the saxon xquery library--

I am working on a java app that should also have xquery support-- for this purpose the java saxon library (www.saxonica.com) is being used.

Now I came across the excellent xquery functions available at xqueryfunctions.com-- and I want to add support for these functions to my app.  In my app, the user can enter a series of commands(incl. XQuery commands) and the app then executes these commands in sequence...

Am I Correct in thinking that, I have to execute the functions at xqueryfunctions.com first, and then execute the user's commands? And I have to do this each time I want the user's commands to be executed?

Is there some way to add 'implicit' support for these functions to my app, so that I do not have to execute those functions everytime I run my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest start by downloading the functx .xq file from xqueryfunctions.com/xq/download.html to an area in your workspace. Then include this in your project using :

```
import module namespace functx = "functx" at "functx-1.0-doc-2007-01.xq"
```